# How do I run in Terminal in Unity Alt + F2?

Tags: 11.04

I don't see any option to run commands in Terminal in the run command dash (or is it lens?) of Unity. Is it available and deactivated, or is the feature missing altogether?

In any case, I think this issue needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't supported in Unity as it was in the GNOME Panel Alt+F2 dialog box, but nevertheless you can work around it by typing this in the Unity Alt+F2 dash:

```
gnome-terminal -e COMMAND
```

Where `command` is the command you wish to run. Unfortunately due to a bug in Unity, you can't run a command with command-line arguments, using the Alt+F2 Unity dash. Hence, you can run:

```
gnome-terminal -e xeyes
```

But running:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'xeyes -display :0'
```

will fail.

Comment: Can you keep us updated on the bug you mentioned? Does the same bug apply on 11.10?

Comment: I'd like to have a fix of this to get the default behaviour as: Press Alt + F2, enter e.g. VIM, and then get vim run in a gnome-terminal. Any hint to accomplish this by default?

Comment: Can we get a link to the bug in question? I'd like to vote for it to be fixed. Seems to still exist in 14.04